# tinymce on multiple instance of same TextArea

Tags: tinymce

Two instances of a partialview are loaded on a page.

Partialview has a textarea with id 'newNote'. Hence, when page loads we have two textarea elements with same id - 'newNote' but under two different containers.

```
<html>
<div id='container1' style="display:none">
--partialview
<textarea id='newNote'/>
</div>
<div id='container2'>
--partialview
<textarea id='newNote'/>
</div>
</html>
```

I want to convert textarea to tinymce Rich text editor based on the active container (in above case container 2).

Can someone pls tell me how to handle two instances with same id.

Answer (score 2):

You should **never** have two elements on the same page with a non-unique id
[HTML4](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2)
[HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Comment: How can i load same partialview in two different jquery tabs? This will create two elements with same id in HTML.

Comment: Thats more of an issue of which framework you are using. You need to figure out how to generate a unique id for your html to be valid.